# Draggable marker and Drawing tool

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the drawing tool with my map. I set the option this as explained in the documentation :

```
  markerOptions: {
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'),
    draggable: true,
    flat: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true
  },
```

However, I cannot drag my marker and the DROPE animation seems to have a bug but works (flash out before droping). getDraggable method returns true :

```
  if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
     markersArray.push(event.overlay);
     alert(event.overlay.getDraggable()); // true
  }
```

When I click on my marker, it ignores it and it drags the map instead. How could I fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code. This code works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Drawing Tools Library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
            ]
          },
          markerOptions: {
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'),
            draggable: true,
            flat: true,
            raiseOnDrag: true
          }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```